# React fails to fetch data from local JSON server when app open in remote machine

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, json-server

My react app for some reason works perfectly well on my local machine, but when I access it from another machine in local network, data is not loaded.
Here is some code:

.env file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://0.0.0.0:3001
```

package file:

```
 "proxy": "http://0.0.0.0:3001"
```

usage in the code:

```
const menusUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/menus";

export function getMenu(menuId) {
  return fetch(`${menusUrl}?id=${menuId}`)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

When I navigate to `localhost:3000`, my app runs great, when I go to `localhost:3001`, my api works, no issues, but as soon as I go to `machine_ip:3000` from another machine in the same network, it fails to load data from api, however, when I go to `machine_ip:3001`, api responses well.

Comment: can you open the `machine_ip:3001` on the browser, any firewall rules set up?

Comment: What is the error in console for `machine_ip:3001`?

Comment: yes, I can open machine_ipe:3001 on the browser firewall is off

Comment: the error is: ET `http://localhost:3001/menu/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`